# Google finance app not working suddenly

Tags: google-apps-script

"FinanceApp" is not defined.

I have been using an application with the Finance app for a while. It has stopped working today.

The function I use is FinanceApp.getStockInfo( ).

Clues anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This service has been stopped. See the sunset schedule page here:  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/sunset